# Why is $\langle A^*x,y\rangle $ the same as $\langle A'^*y,x\rangle$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vectors, inner-products, transpose

If $A$ is a $3\times 3$-matrix, while $x$ and $y$ are a vector point with x,y,z.
Why is the dot product of $\langle A^*x,y\rangle$ the same as the dot product of $\langle A'^*y,x\rangle$

($A'$ being the transposed matrix)

Comment: What is $A^*$? The conjugate transpose? If it is, is $\langle,\rangle$ a Hermitian inner product or not?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For column vectors $\mathbf{u},\mathbf{v}$, the scalar product is
$$\langle \mathbf{u}, \mathbf{v} \rangle=\mathbf{u}^T \mathbf{v}.  $$
Therefore
$$\langle A \mathbf{x},\mathbf{y}\rangle = (A \mathbf{x})^T \mathbf{y}=\mathbf{x}^T A^T \mathbf{y}=\langle \mathbf{x},A^T \mathbf{y} \rangle = \langle A^T \mathbf{y}, \mathbf{x}\rangle. $$